# How to use sed to replace the url name in the yaml files for an env variable

Tags: linux, shell, replace

**Requirement:** I have a repo in the GitHub with a lot of subfolders. Currently I have YAML files in the repo with the below HTTP and HTTPS URLs. Notice the proxy URLs for both HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY are same -

```
env:
    - name: HTTP_PROXY
      value: http://jump.proxy.com:3128
    - name: HTTPS_PROXY
      value: http://jump.proxy.com:3128
```

Now here I need to change the above values for HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY to different URLs, say as below -

```
env:
    - name: HTTP_PROXY
      value: http://newjump.proxy.com:80
    - name: HTTPS_PROXY
      value: https://newjump.proxy.com:443
```

Notice the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY values are different in the above change.

**Solution I tried:** I am able to replace the jump proxy URL with the new jump proxy URL using the below sed command on macOS -

```
LC_ALL=C find /git-repo -type f -name '*.*' -exec sed -i '' s#http://jump.proxy.com:3128#https://newjump.proxy.com:443#g {} +
```

But here the main problem is as I am searching with the `http://jump.proxy.com:3128` URL it replaces the values for both HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY with the same `https://newjump.proxy.com:443` URL. I want the HTTP_PROXY value as `http://newjump.proxy.com:80` which is different from the HTTPS_PROXY value after running sed but not able to figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: Try `sed -i -e '/name: HTTP_PROXY/{n' -e 's#http://jump.proxy.com:3128#https://newjump.proxy.com:443#' -e '}'`

Answer (score 2):

Using [yq](/questions/tagged/yq)

```sh
yq eval '
    with(.env[]; select(.name == "HTTP_PROXY") | .value = strenv(HTTP_PROXY))
    | with(.env[]; select(.name == "HTTPS_PROXY") | .value = strenv(HTTPS_PROXY))
' file.yml
```

It would have been nice to write

```sh
yq eval 'with(.env[]; .value = strenv(.name))' file.yml
```

but the strenv() function takes a literal env var name, and I couldn't figure out how to manipulate eval() to expand the .name path.